# Closed Form for the integral $\int_0^1 \left(\frac{e^{2 x-2}x}{1-x^2}-\frac{e^{3 x-3} x}{1-x^2}\right)\,dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Can anybody find a closed form for the following integral?  I am stuck.

$$\int_0^1 \left(\frac{e^{2 x-2}
   x}{1-x^2}-\frac{e^{3 x-3} x}{1-x^2}\right) \,
   dx$$

I just thought of this integral, there is no reason I need to compute it.

I tried writing $\frac{1}{1-x^2}$ as a series and then exchanging the order of summation and integration.  Then I computed the integral of each summand.  But this got a little messy.  To find this integral I set up a recurrence relation with Integration by Parts.  Eventually I got:

$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \left(\frac{(-1)^{1-2 n} 3^{-2 n-2}
   (\Gamma (2 n+2)-\Gamma (2 n+2,-3))}{e^3}+\frac{(-1)^{-2 n} 2^{-2 n-2} (\Gamma
   (2 n+2)-\Gamma (2 n+2,-2))}{e^2}\right)$$

This involves the incomplete gamma function, and so I am stuck.  The main reason this way did not work was because the recurrence relation did not end up having a nice closed form.

Answer (score 3):

I see no interesting property of the integral. You may begin by noticing that

$$ \int \frac{e^{ax}}{x+b} \, dx = e^{-ab} \operatorname{Ei}(a(x+b)), $$

where $\operatorname{Ei}$ is the [*exponential integral*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral). With aid of partial fraction decoposition, you should be able to compute

$$ \int_{0}^{1} \frac{(e^{2x-2} - e^{3x-3}) x}{1-x^2} \, dx
= \lim_{r \to 1^-} \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{r} (e^{2x-2} - e^{3x-3})\left( \frac{1}{1-x} - \frac{1}{1+x} \right) \, dx. $$